# Android tabs: Can i put something next to the tab and customize tab styles?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm trying to create tabs that don't fill up the entire width.

I currently am using ActionBar tabs and just made that blue + a tab as well, but unfortunately it stretches it to make it equal width.

Is there any way I can do this using action bar tabs? If not, can I do it with TabHost/TabWidget? I want the content of the page to be a ViewPager which controls the actual page content.

My current XML file looks as simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When I tried out a TabHost, I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

          <TabWidget 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >

            </TabWidget>
            <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:background="#00F"
                android:text="+"
                >
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Which gives me something like:

[image]

But I don't know where my ViewPager fits into that.

I also am having trouble figuring out how to make the following customizations to the action bar tab:

1. Lower casing instead of all caps
2. Tab height
3. Selected bar color
4. Selected typeface
5. Selected/unselected text color
6. Font size

Any ideas would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the "TabWidget" to "LinearLayout" or any layout and add whenever you need.

For example to make tabs fill only 0.65 of the screen width

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:background="@color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
```